# Getting Contacts detail with Contact_ID in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

how to get contacts detail with Contact Id in android???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will return you the contact number with the given contact id.

```
ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(
        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
        new String[]{id}, null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    phones.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
} 

cursor.close();
return(phones);
```

Here `id` the contact_id.

Answer (score 0):

**To fetch the contacts from the phone Uri 
We need to add the permission in android Manifest**